# Better way to use tuple as list of arguments

Tags: python

I have a function that returns some items as a tuple. This function breaks a range of values into quintiles

Example:

```
def my_function1():

    #does some stuff

    return first_quintile_max, first_quintile_min, second_quintile_max, second_quintile_min, third_quintile_max, third_quintile_min, fourth_quintile_max, fourth_quintile_min, fifth_quintile_max, fifth_quintile_min
```

So now my output from this function is a tuple (range_of_values), with 10 items in it.

```
range_of_values = my_function1()
```

I've named these (not as namedtuples, but I suppose I could do that) and used them as arguments for the next function:

```
    first_quintile_max = range_of_values[0]
    first_quintile_min = range_of_values[1]
    second_quintile_max = range_of_values[2]
    second_quintile_min = range_of_values[3]
    third_quintile_max = range_of_values[4]
    third_quintile_min = range_of_values[5]
    fourth_quintile_max = range_of_values[6]
    fourth_quintile_min = range_of_values[7]
    fifth_quintile_max = range_of_values[8]
    fifth_quintile_min = range_of_values[9]
```

Now I run the next function, using these as my arguments:

```
my_function2(first_quintile_max, first_quintile_min, second_quintile_max, second_quintile_min,
                      third_quintile_max, third_quintile_min, fourth_quintile_max, fourth_quintile_min, 
                      fifth_quintile_max, fifth_quintile_min)
```

I can't help but think there is a more elegant way to feed this tuple into my second function as arguments. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: `my_function2(*my_function1())`?

Comment: assuming the order is the same `my_function2(*my_function1())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `my_function2(* range_of_values)`. You'll have to assure that `range_of_values` is sorted the same way the `my_function2` parameters do.

Comment: If I managed to help you, please, consider selecting my message as accepted answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's not too great to pass so many values as a parameter into a function. It's better instead to pack them into a data structure, like a dictionary:

```
quintiles = {
    'first': (max, min),
    'second': (max, min),
    # ...
}
```

Then return this from your function. Then you just pass the dictionary to your other function and access the elements like this:

```
quintiles['first']
```

Hope that helps!